# My fifteenth puzzle. And it's perfect

Tags: riddle, cipher, humor

You know those people with 'brilliant' logic that you ***just can't argue*** with?

**Example:**

> Jackasses have long ears
>
> Carl is a jackass
>
> Therefore, Carl has long ears

Well, here's a puzzle for you guys, because they're **fun**.

*One day*, I woke up.

But **SUDDENLY**  as I went outside, there was another ROOM with **CONCRETE WALLS**

I went back to go to my room and climb out of the window or something, but of course the door slammed behind me.

I found the following -

> A bomb with about 56800 seconds left
>
> A light bulb
>
> A door needing a 1 digit passcode, and also saying **DO NOT GUESS**
>
> A link - [A Test Called Failure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SGSMR1cdCGzphAbMQPB0DkEhq6I--9TRNuM0xZ7hx6Y/edit?usp=sharing)
>
> Another link - [Don't change the settings](https://codebeautify.org/encrypt-decrypt)

There was also a poem

> Haha, Alto. I made a perfect puzzle, just in time for school!
>
> And nobody can figure this out for you!
>
> Hackers, coders, computers, and a clinic!
>
> Anyone will give up, in a minute! Tada! ~~~~Jack

And 2 strings:

> LBkNRhMMN3P7GaYci/3lg9iwEvP/FSl6FqgQySfmHpVP3nSj9kUJA5L+sacD9iYGvTnPkaBtqfWey9grn1Jjr+YamE/ReNr0voumR86RYg7bamXFlReXE5X3CgUHPUj2KvukVUqD7Keziee8WQL1FgaSqofe4qrFcs4tUCgKqGvtt4dDAnhIwN2NWJEbdaAVEw==
>
> 5/rjtUhWTRhqP9dClogRRAR/U5pHvEevaOpf4NPouIG0qLG/Aw4aq5c0UTuYzsNAeg38EWGcQMgdbmuy/cbRwaCKYDp0U6/5p17SWL5R1K588966oNIupVJxb2nJg2oaNRkskpRAwjXNZYpDziWUh5atdObL72daqI0OgVf7aXQMZ/22nnrmZVBdL/N9vdJdeg==

Here's another silly joke, probably put there to distract you guys:

> A cheetah and a lion were racing. The cheetah won. Then, the lion said "***YOU CHEETAH!!!***", and the cheetah said "***YOU LION!!!!***" AHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA

Note that a jackass is another name for a donkey, and that 'ahem' *JACK* laughs too much.

Also, every once in awhile, i'll update the time left in the bomb.

01:50 PM, 22 September 2018 (UTC)

**SOLVED**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I push in the number

> 7

Because

> the acrostic on the poem is haha.  using this for the key on the first encryption gives
> "Wow, you're good, but not better than me! See you next time, "wow!", the answer is 7.  P.S. The second string is just for the key HAHA, not haha." 
>  the second string, with key HAHA does indeed give essentially the same message.

I probably blow up because I missed something, but... ah well!